# Error in Swift: "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa208d0a2b0"

Tags: swift, xcode, nib, sigabrt, unrecognized-selector

I have tried following a tutorial on YouTube by CraniumCode, to learn the syntax for Swift. The tutorial is to create the game ZigZag.

When I press the Play button I am sent to the game screen containing 10 randomly places pillars and the ball. The game then stops, and I get the error at the top, aswell as

> Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with
>   identifier "user.App".

First time asker, long time reader, still haven't found a viable solution.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func Play(_ sender: Any) {

    self.GameOver.isHidden = true
    self.Play.isHidden = true
    self.Retry.isHidden = true
    self.Logo.isHidden = true


    self.Ball.center.x = 178.0
    self.Ball.center.y = 390.0

    self.Pillar1.center = CGPoint (x: 175.0, y: 436.0)
    self.Pillar2.center = CGPoint (x: 214.0, y: 407.0)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.045, target:self,
        selector: Selector("movement"),
        userInfo:nil, repeats:true)


    self.Pillar3.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar2.center.x, y: 
    Pillar2.center.y)
    self.Pillar4.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar3.center.x, y: 
    Pillar3.center.y)
    self.Pillar5.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar4.center.x, y: 
    Pillar4.center.y)
    self.Pillar6.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar5.center.x, y: 
    Pillar5.center.y)
    self.Pillar7.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar6.center.x, y: 
    Pillar6.center.y)
    self.Pillar8.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar7.center.x, y: 
    Pillar7.center.y)
    self.Pillar9.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar8.center.x, y: 
    Pillar8.center.y)
    self.Pillar10.center = pillarPlacement(x: Pillar9.center.x, y: 
    Pillar9.center.y)



    self.Ball.isHidden = false

    self.Pillar1.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar2.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar3.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar4.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar5.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar6.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar7.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar8.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar9.isHidden = false
    self.Pillar10.isHidden = false

}





@IBAction func Retry(_ sender: Any) {
}


@IBOutlet var GameView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var Pillar1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar9: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Pillar10: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var Retry: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var Play: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var Logo: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var GameOver: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var Ball: UIImageView!

var timer = Timer()
var TapsValid:Bool?
var BallRight:Bool?
var BallChange:Bool?


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.GameOver.isHidden = true
    self.Play.isHidden = false
    self.Retry.isHidden = true
    self.Logo.isHidden = false
    self.Ball.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar1.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar2.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar3.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar4.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar5.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar6.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar7.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar8.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar9.isHidden = true
    self.Pillar10.isHidden = true

}


func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if (TapsValid == true) {
        if (BallRight == true) {
            BallChange = false
        } else {
            BallChange = true
        }
    }
}


func movement() {

    if (BallChange == false) {
        BallRight = false
    } else {
        BallRight = true
    }
    if (BallRight == true) {
        Ball.center.x += 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    } else {
        Ball.center.x -= 6.5
        Ball.center.y -= 0.5
    }

    Ball.center.y += 0.5
    Pillar1.center.y += 5
    Pillar2.center.y += 5
    Pillar3.center.y += 5
    Pillar4.center.y += 5
    Pillar5.center.y += 5
    Pillar6.center.y += 5
    Pillar7.center.y += 5
    Pillar8.center.y += 5
    Pillar9.center.y += 5
    Pillar10.center.y += 5

    Pillar1.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y,  
    pillarNumber: 1)
    Pillar2.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y, 
    pillarNumber: 2)
    Pillar3.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y, 
    pillarNumber: 3)
    Pillar4.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y, 
    pillarNumber: 4)
    Pillar5.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y, 

    pillarNumber: 5)
    Pillar6.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y,       
    pillarNumber: 6)
    Pillar7.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y,  
    pillarNumber: 7)
    Pillar8.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y, 
    pillarNumber: 8)
    Pillar9.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y, 
    pillarNumber: 9)
    Pillar10.center = movePillarUp(floatx: Pillar1.center.x,
                                  floaty: Pillar1.center.y, 
    pillarNumber: 10)
}


func movePillarUp(floatx: CGFloat, floaty: CGFloat, pillarNumber: Int ) 
-> (CGPoint) {

    var center = CGPoint(x: floatx, y: floaty)


    if checkPillarPosition(y: floaty) == true {
        switch pillarNumber{
        case 1:
            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar1)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar10.center.x, y: self.Pillar10.center.y)
            break
        case 2:
            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar2)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar1.center.x, y: self.Pillar1.center.y)
            break
        case 3:
                            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar3)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar2.center.x, y: self.Pillar2.center.y)
            break
        case 4:
                            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar4)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar3.center.x, y: self.Pillar3.center.y)
            break
        case 5:
                            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar5)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar4.center.x, y: self.Pillar4.center.y)
            break
        case 6:
                            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar6)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar5.center.x, y: self.Pillar5.center.y)
            break
        case 7:
                            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar7)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar6.center.x, y: self.Pillar6.center.y)
            break
        case 8:
                            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar8)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar7.center.x, y: self.Pillar7.center.y)
            break
        case 9:
                            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar9)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar8.center.x, y: self.Pillar8.center.y)
            break
        case 10:
            GameView.sendSubview(toBack:Pillar10)
            center = pillarPlacement(x: self.Pillar9.center.x, y: self.Pillar9.center.y)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return(center)
}

func checkPillarPosition(y: CGFloat) -> (Bool) {
    return (y > 720)
}


func pillarPlacement(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> (CGPoint) {
    var pillarNewX: CGFloat
    var pillarNewY: CGFloat
    let random: Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)

    if (random == 1) {
        pillarNewX = x + 39
        pillarNewY = y - 29

        if (pillarNewX >= 319) {
            pillarNewX = x - 40
            pillarNewY = y - 30
        }
    } else {
        pillarNewX = x - 40
        pillarNewY = y - 30
        if (pillarNewX <= 17) {
            pillarNewX = x + 39
            pillarNewY = y - 29
        }
    }
    let newPillarCenter = CGPoint(x: pillarNewX, y: pillarNewY)
    return(newPillarCenter)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Comment: Don't start method with uppercase letter... Edit: Don't start anything except Class/Struct/Protocol/Type name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:0.045, target:self,
    selector: #selector(self.movement), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
```

And adding @objc infront of func movement()removed the error!